# How to have a user select images and then insert them into Word PDF?

Tags: vba, image, ms-word

I'm looking for a way to bring up the file explorer so the user can choose a picture or folder of pictures and then inserts it into a generated pdf document.

I have used multiple subs to use a predetermined picture but for this application, the picture will be different every time.

```
Set wdApp = New Word.Application

With wdApp
   .Visible = True
   .Activate

    .Documents.Add
    With .Selection

        .BoldRun
        .Font.Size = 20
        .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
        .TypeText TextBox2.Value
        .TypeText Chr(13)
        .BoldRun

        .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
        .Font.Size = 16
        .TypeText "Report"
        .TypeText Chr(13)
```

I have the above code to create the word document. I need to insert the picture after the text.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: Is it possible to make it so when the above code is ran, the file explorer comes up so the user can choose a picture or a folder of pictures. After they choose the picture it will be inserted in the word documented that is generated from the above code

Comment: if so how do i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [File Dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.filedialog) to allow your user to select pictures.

Below is an example of how to use it, you'll just have to update it for your specific needs. Check out the documentation above to see more options as well.

Change `.AllowMultiSelect` to `True` and then you can loop each file the user selected.

```vb
Private Sub TestingFileDialog()

    Dim Fd As FileDialog
    Set Fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    With Fd

        'GENERAL SETTINGS
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Please select a picture"
        .ButtonName = "Choose a picture"
        .InitialFileName = "c:\"
        .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList

        'FILE FILTERS
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "JPG", "*.JPG"
        .Filters.Add "PNG", "*.PNG"


        'SHOW FORM, WILL RETURN TRUE IF USER SELECTS A FILE
        If .Show = True Then

          'Get file name
          Dim FilePath As String
          FilePath = .SelectedItems(1)

          'do whatever you need to from here...

        Else
            'No file chosen, do something else.

        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

To add images use `wdApp.Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture`. This will take in your file path that the user selects.

Using your code it might look something like:

```vb
Sub AddImagesToWordDocument()

    Set wdApp = New Word.Application

    With wdApp
        .Visible = True
        .Activate
        .Documents.Add

        With .Selection
            .BoldRun
            .Font.Size = 20
            .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
            .TypeText TextBox2.Value
            .TypeText Chr(13)
            .BoldRun

            .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
            .Font.Size = 16
            .TypeText "Report"
            .TypeText Chr(13)

            Dim Fd As FileDialog
            Set Fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
            Fd.AllowMultiSelect = True
            Fd.Filters.Clear
            Fd.Filters.Add "JPG", "*.JPG"
            Fd.Filters.Add "PNG", "*.PNG"
            If Fd.Show = True Then

                'Loop files and add them
                Dim FileIndex As Long
                For FileIndex = 1 To Fd.SelectedItems.Count
                    .InlineShapes.AddPicture Fd.SelectedItems(FileIndex)
                Next FileIndex
            Else
                'No file chosen, do something else if need be.
            End If

        End With

    End With


End Sub
```

Comment: @masoncowing was this the answer you were looking for? If so please accept this as the correct answer, otherwise add comments to where you are at on this so that people visiting this question can have some more references.

Comment: This part helped very much with choosing the file, however I am still unclear on how to insert the picture into my generated word document.

Comment: @masoncowing I added a small section showing you how to add images. It will just take in the filepath that the user selects. Here is a link that shows many other ways of [Adding images to a Word Document](https://software-solutions-online.com/word-vba-insert-images/)

Comment: @masoncowing was the last bit helpful to you in answering your question?

Comment: This did help me to add a picture to the document on word, however it inserted the picture to the document that I was running the macro from instead of the document that was generated from running the macro. Pretty confusing but I'm trying to work through it.